# How to support mp3 download from all browsers

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, mp3

I want to offer an mp3 file and have it available for download from every browser possible.

It seems to be a mess.

The link already has the download attribute, [which works in some places.](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)

Then I tried with the apache configRewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=download$
RewriteRule .*\.mp3$ - [L,T=applicaton/octet-stream]
```

or

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$">
  ForceType audio/mpeg
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*/?([^/]*)$" FILENAME=$1
  Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e"
  UnsetEnv FILENAME
</FilesMatch>
```

And others I found online but none seem to let me download from mobile chrome on Android, is there any all around solution or combination so solutions?

Answer (score 0):

i use php code like this  to download file

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-type: application/mp3");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($fullPath) . "\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($fullPath));
readfile($fullPath);
```

Comment: Not sure what this accomplishes :(

Comment: if i understand your question, some browser start audio playing mp3 instead of downloading the file... so i usually call a php script passing the mp3 name then on server side execute that script...